# Problem with Firebase in SwiftUI macos app. [Running InstanceID on a simulator doesn't have APNS. Use prod profile by default.]

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I wanted to run my swiftui app on macos, unfortunately i can still see error That

> Running InstanceID on a simulator doesn't have APNS. Use prod
>   profile by default.

I used the code from firebase messaging docs to initialize firebase messaging and later on I wanted to get instance id token.
While using Xcode I don't get any other errors instead of this which I mentioned. That's why I decided to archive my app and run it independently
outside Xcode. Unfortunately I still can see in console error message about running in simulator. When I run that code on my physical iPhone everything works properly.

[Xcode log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXHlA.png)

[Mac console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c2Mx.png)

Does anyone know what should I change or how should I archive the app properly in order to firebase not detect my app as simulator?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you provide us with some code and specific errors that you receive on running your app?

Comment: @NathanEllis  I edited my post now. Sorry for not providing any more accurate details.